# Empty ClassPath.from(classLoader) in Java 11

Tags: java, mockito, java-11, powermockito

I'm migrating our code base to use java 11 (openJDK) and I have a lot of tests with powermock and mockito. The tests are using JSONs to build objects based on a provided class name. The searching for class is done by the following code:

```
        for (final ClassPath.ClassInfo info : ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClasses()) {
            if (info.getName().endsWith("." + pClassName)) {
                return info.getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
```

When I debug the code, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() returns [image]
But ClassPath.from(loader).getTopLevelClasses() has 0 elements in it.
My dependencies are:

1. jackson.core 2.10.3
2. junit 4.13
3. surefire 2.22.1
4. compiler 3.8.0
5. shade 3.2.1
6. powermock 2.0.5
7. mockito 3.3.0

I've excluded bytebuddy from powermock-api-mockito2 and mockito-core, cause it's already added in powermock-module-junit4

Surefire configuration is:

```
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>true</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <argLine>-Xms256m -Xmx2800m -Dmvn.forkNumber=${surefire.forkNumber} -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit</argLine>
                </configuration>
```

Comment: Code trying to analyze the class path will not see classes an the module path. Likewise, code assuming that the system class loader is a subclass of `URLClassLoader` will not work.

Comment: In fact when you mentioned this I notice that the guava ( ClassPath ) needs to be updated and that;s the reason. Ty for the suggestion!